Retrieve final value of a time series variable counter in openmodelica
I have a binary activation signal which varies between 0 and 1. Based on that signal I have built a simple counter in modelica language as follows.
model Counter
  discrete Real counter(start=0);
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput u
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-130,-18},{-90,22}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RealExpression realExpression(y=counter)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-70,-28},{-2,32}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput y
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{96,-8},{116,12}})));
equation 
  when u>0 then
    counter=pre(counter)+1;
  end when;
  connect(realExpression.y, y)
    annotation (Line(points={{1.4,2},{106,2}}, color={0,0,127}));
  annotation (Diagram(coordinateSystem(extent={{-100,-20},{100,40}})), Icon(
        coordinateSystem(extent={{-100,-20},{100,40}})));
end Counter;

However, it return me value in time series as well. I would prefer to have a final (integer) value at the end of simulation time which allows to calculate another constant value. I.e. if the counter is 0,1,2,...,10; I want to retrieve the output as counter = 10 (single value) and not a time dependant curve as in picture.


In the scripting .mos file you can use val(counter, 4e4).

I am not sure I understand you correctly, but it seems that you want to know how to conveniently retrieve the final value of a time series for post-processing.
If you work in a Python environment using PyFMI the code would be as follows.
model = load_fmu('system.fmu')
sim_res = model.simulate(final_time=4E4)
counter_final_value = sim_res['counter.y'][-1]

Where system is a Modelica code including the Model Counter.  And you export your Modelica-model as an FMU from your Modelica-software.
I can agree that it is not very efficient to store all time series values before the final value, but I am not sure here is any Modelica concept that address your problem.

In case you would want the value in the model itself, you could use the terminal statement to retrieve that value (using sample() to count some value). Additionally, you could compute the "another constant value" in the termal section:
model LastValue
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Time startTime = 0.1;
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Time sampleInterval = 0.1;

  Integer counter(start=0, fixed=true);
  Integer counterLast(start=-1, fixed=true);

equation 
  when sample(startTime, sampleInterval) then
    counter =  pre(counter) + 1;
  end when;

  when terminal() then
    counterLast = counter;
  end when;

  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end LastValue;

